# Is it possible to expand a collection to multiple parameters of a function

Tags: vector, parameters, rust

I have a `Vec` which has following elements:

```
let v = vec!(["ABC", "DEFG", "HIJKLMN"],
             ["foobar", "bar", "foo"],
             ["foobar2", "bar2", "foo2"])
```

I am using a macro `table!` from library `prettytable-rs` which accepts parameters as follows:

```
let table = table!(["ABC", "DEFG", "HIJKLMN"],
                   ["foobar", "bar", "foo"],
                   ["foobar2", "bar2", "foo2"]);

table.printstd();
```

Basically I want to explode the `Vec` `v` and pass its elements as multiple parameters to macro `table!` or any function/method for that matter. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Macros work on the syntax trees, and cannot deconstruct an existing variable like this.

However, using the `table!` macro isn't the only way to construct a `prettytable::Table`. If you look at the doc, you will notice that there is [an implementation of](https://docs.rs/prettytable-rs/0.7.0/prettytable/struct.Table.html#impl-From%3CT%3E):

```
impl<T, A, B> From<T> for Table where
    B: ToString,
    A: IntoIterator<Item = B>,
    T: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
```

which means that you can construct a table from anything that is a doubly iterable, yielding something that implements `ToString`.

This allows to construct the table like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate prettytable;
use prettytable::Table;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![
        ["ABC", "DEFG", "HIJKLMN"],
        ["foobar", "bar", "foo"],
        ["foobar2", "bar2", "foo2"],
    ];

    let table = prettytable::Table::from(v.iter());

    // Print the table to stdout
    table.printstd();
}
```